# Run a command in a tty and send/receive data from it in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a program that requires a tty to work. How do I run this program in a separate tty to my shell and then interact with it? (by writing to the interactive stdin, reading from stdout)?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) program is for. See that URL and/or the [expect(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) man page on your system, if it is already installed.